# Fabricator.js: Is there a way to access material front matter from a child template?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, templating

In a fabricator app in my parent.html I have...

```
---
title: awesome
other: also awesome
---
{{> widgetTemplate}}
{{other}}
```

And then in my child.html i have something like

```
<h1>This is {{this.parent.title}}</h1>
```

I know this.parent.title doesn't work, but anyone know if there is a way to access the title front material from the child template like the parent template accesses its front matter like other without bringing in javascript for each template?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a fabricator.js tag, and i have nowhere near the reputation to make one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimentation instead of front matter I can just define the variables I need on the go in the templating simple as:

```
{{> widgetTemplate title="awesome"}}
```

and then in the template

```
<h1>This is {{title}}</h1>
```